# Listen for Change of Value in Array of Inputs and Update the Array if there is a Change

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I'm working on a functionality that requires me to pull the values of several inputs (for product quantities), save them to an array and update that array if any of the input values change. I have some code working that updates the array if there's a change, but doesn't update it if I turn that array into an array of objects with key-value pairs. See my code below:

**HTML With Three Inputs**

```js
// Get Input Quantities as an HTML Array
const quantities = document.getElementsByName('updates[]');
console.log(quantities);

// Get Input Quantities Values as an Array
let quantitiesValues = [];

// Loop Through Input Quantities Array
for (let i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++) {
  
  // Push Values to Array
  let values = quantities[i].value;
  quantitiesValues.push(values);
  
  // Change Values in Array
  quantities[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
    quantitiesValues[i] = this.value;
  
  });
}
console.log(quantitiesValues);


// Add Input Value Key
  const productQuanities = quantitiesValues.map(element => {
  return { input_value: element };
});
console.log(productQuanities);
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="5" />
  </div>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="4" />
  </div>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="3" />
  </div>
  <script type="module" src="src/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

So if I changed the first input value to 10, the output of `productQuantities` should be:

```
[{input_value: 10}, {input_value: 5}, {input_value: 3}];
```

### I'm new to JS hence all the comments and console.logs. Any help is appreciated!

Playcode Link:
https://playcode.io/934918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Reference the <form>
const form = document.forms[0];
// Syntax: bracket index notaion -- 0 is the first <form> tag
console.log(form);

/*
Collect all <input> into a HTMLFormControlsCollection then convert it
into an array
*/
const fc = Array.from(form.elements["updates[]"]);
// Syntax: X = formObj.elements["shared name of <input>s"]
//         Array.from(X)
console.log(fc);

// Get current values
const values = fc.map(input => Object.assign({}, {'input_value': input.value}));
// Return: [{input_value: "5"}, {input_value: "4"}, {input_value: "3"}]
console.log(values);

// Bind the input event to each <input>
// function update() is the event handler
fc.forEach(input => input.oninput = update);

// Define event handler
// Pass the event object "e"
function update(e) {
  // Get the index of the <input> the user typed data into
  let index = fc.indexOf(this);
  /*
  Assign the value at the index of "values" array with the current
  value of the <input>
  */
  values.forEach((obj, idx) => {
    if (idx === index) {
      obj["input_value"] = this.value;
    }
  });
  // Log "values" array -- updates are immediate
  // User enters 10 on the first <input>
  // values = [{input_value: "10"}, {input_value: "4"}, {input_value: "3"}]
  console.log(values);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="5" />
  </div>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="4" />
  </div>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="3" />
  </div>
  <script type="module" src="src/script.js"></script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making a mistake. just put the productQuanities inside the event listener.

just like below

```js
// Get Input Quantities as an HTML Array
const quantities = document.getElementsByName('updates[]');
console.log(quantities);

// Get Input Quantities Values as an Array
let quantitiesValues = [];

// Loop Through Input Quantities Array
for (let i = 0; i < quantities.length; i++) {
  
  // Push Values to Array
  let values = quantities[i].value;
  quantitiesValues.push(values);
  
  // Change Values in Array
  quantities[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
    quantitiesValues[i] = this.value;
    const productQuanities = quantitiesValues.map(element => {
      return { input_value: element };
    });
      console.log(productQuanities);
  });
}
```

check this [codeplay](https://playcode.io/935018/)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I hope that this would help:

```js
const quantities = document.querySelectorAll('[name="updates[]"]');
const button = document.querySelector('#submit');

// Get the values before you do anything
let finalValues = getFinalValues(Array.from(quantities));

quantities.forEach((quantity, i) => {
  quantity.addEventListener('input', function () {
    // Update the values on change of the input values
    finalValues = getFinalValues(Array.from(quantities));
    // Need array.from to convert type NodeList from querySelectorAll to type array
  })
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(finalValues)                        
});

function getFinalValues(inputs) {
  return inputs.map(element => ({ input_value: element.value }));
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="5" />
  </div>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="4" />
  </div>
  <div class="scd-item__qty">
    <input class="scd-item__qty_input" name="updates[]" value="3" />
  </div>
  
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  <script type="module" src="src/script.js"></script>
</html>
```